# How to "scale and rotate image" when hovering over text aswell?

Tags: html, css

I created the jsfiddle, to show you what i mean exactly.

When hovering over the text, it should also be possible that the background takes the effect like when hovering over the img/div. Currently the hover effect only works when hovering over the div/img and not when hovering over the text in the middle of the image.. The "a" link should work on the div and text aswell.

https://jsfiddle.net/o5sxhssv/

HTML:

```
<!--First image-->

<div class="category_images_item">
<a href="">
<span>Watches</span>

<div class="category_images_img" style="background:url(https://static.pexels.com/photos/1279/fashion-wristwatch-time-watch.jpg)no-repeat center;background-size:cover;">

</div>
</a>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.category_images{
 margin: 0 auto
 }
 .category_images_item{
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: black;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all .8s ease;
  margin: 10px;float: left
  }
  .category_images_item span{
   color: white;
   font-weight: bold;
   font-size: 50px;
   font-style: italic;
   z-index: 100;
   position: absolute;
   width: 100%;
   text-align: center;
   top: 150px
   }
.category_images_img{
 background-size: cover;
 width: 400px;
 height: 400px;
 transition: all .8s ease;
 opacity: 0.7
 }
 .category_images_img:hover{
  transform: scale(1.03) rotate(-1deg);
  opacity: 0.5
  }
```

Thanks alot!! :))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just have to change your hover css rule to this:

```
.category_images_item:hover .category_images_img{
    transform: scale(1.03) rotate(-1deg);
    opacity: 0.5
 }
```

put the hover event on your container and apply the css to the child!
EDIT: updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/o5sxhssv/1/

Comment: Thanks alot!! Works like a charm :)) didn't think it was that easy haha

Answer (score 0):

Try this, the anchor tags container both the text and image, so you want the hover on that:

```
.category_images_item a:hover .category_images_img{
   transform: scale(1.03) rotate(-1deg);
   opacity: 0.5
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pointer-events: none` on `.category_images_item span`

Using `pointer-events: none` says that the cursor does not interact with that element.

Then to make the whole area clickable, make the a element display as a block, this will make the a cover the entire area of it's parent element.

```
.category_images_item a {
  display: block;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/o5sxhssv/2/

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to change the markup, then you could rearrange your code like this:

```
    <div class="category_images">

    <!--First image-->

        <div class="category_images_item">
          <a href="">

             <div class="category_images_img" style="background:url(https://static.pexels.com/photos/1279/fashion-wristwatch-time-watch.jpg)no-repeat center;background-size:cover;">
             <span>Watches</span></div> 
          </a> 
        </div> 
    </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tung3yx2/